# Getting condenser mic and headphones to work together (17.04)

Tags: sound, microphone

PC: HP Pavilion 23
OS: Ubuntu 17.04

I have two headphone jacks on my PC. I have hooked up my new condenser mic (Neewer NW-800) to both jacks and while I am able to record, I get no sound when I try to playback my recording.

Before you ask: yes, I do have the mic connected to Phantom Power.

So far, I have only tried the on-board speakers; I'm afraid that if I connected headphones they will not work.

I have 3 microphones in my sound settings: 2 are connected to Webcams (one onboard and one that is part of an external cam) and the Internal Mic. I muted the two webcam mics to make sure they were not interfering with the recording.

Is there something that I am missing in the process? Any and all help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was trying to rely on Alsa when the regular settings were just fine. :)